# Wait, what's our site's tag-line?

Tags: bug, status-completed

"the CiviCRM" sounds pretty weird.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, good catch. It was a bad copy/paste from the site description. It's fixed now, but performance caching will take awhile to update that page before the change goes "live."

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the fix.